# Does MW3 have LAN support?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

It is almost too much to ask these days, but it is an important factor because I like to play with friends without connection troubles and zero lag.

Is it going to be possible to play Modern Warfare 3 on LAN?

If yes, what are the parameters?

I really do not care about turned off achievements or whatnot.

Comment: Can we just change the title to, "Does MW3..." since it's out in a few hours?

Comment: Make sure when you are trying to play over LAN that all players/devices are running the same version of the game. For xboxes, that means connect each to XBOX live and make sure they don't have any updates to download.

Comment: @DesignerGuy Steam takes care of updates on PC.

Comment: @Bora - Got it. I just mentioned it because I remember doing a COD LAN party and having connectivity trouble between boxes because of version mismatches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only have access to the Xbox 360 version of the game but here are some of the options that you can set up.

- Pick any of the maps
- The standard game types of: FFA, TDM, S&D, sabotage, domination, headquarters, CTF, demolition, kill confirmed, and team defender
- And alternate modes of: drop zone, team juggernaut, juggernaut, gun game, infection, and one in the chamber
- Enable custom game options such as number of lives, create customized default classes, turn off the kill cam, turn off killstreaks, etc.
- You can create custom default classes and assign them to each team.
- You can also allow custom classes, but restrict choices. This means you can turn off individual guns, entire gun classes (assault, smg, lmg, etc), turn off perks, etc.

---

Yes, MW3 will support LAN play.

> Infinity Ward creative strategist, Robert Bowling has been answering
>   questions on Twitter in the aftermath of the Call of Duty XP event
>   that happened over the course of the weekend. Dedicated Servers for
>   Modern Warfare 3 have already been confirmed, but Bowling also
>   mentions that LAN play will be possible, which certainly wasn’t a
>   given, considering how Modern Warfare 3 will tie in heavily with
>   Activision’s online Call of Duty Elite service.
>
> “Yes, #MW3 has LAN,” Bowling tweets, “along with detailed class
>   restriction control + default class creation option.”
>
> The class restriction control will give LAN gamers the ability to
>   “restrict any weapon, equipment, perk, deathstreak, secondary,
>   attachment, ANYTHING from being used when setting up game,” Bowling
>   adds.

Source: [PCGamer](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/09/06/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3-will-have-lan-support-improved-theatre-mode-no-zombies/)

Comment: Since I changed the title, you should edit your answer, after trying out the game on a LAN session ;)

Comment: Alright, when it arrives tomorrow I shall do just that

Comment: @Bora Is that the sort of thing you wanted to know?